# How to build multiple nested form objects based on a condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a nested form between lets say employee and address. In the customer form i have included fields for address. 
I have a field called status in employee. when a particular status is selected , lets say "a" . When the status a is selected and submitted a new address object form should be shown and we should be add one more address to the employee. 
I have tried the link to add as shown in the doc, but i want the new form to be auto shown when a status is selected and submitted.

Comment: see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers?)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a view selector to the selected status box...

Let's say ID of status box is "#status-box"

Then once it changes.. fire an AJAX call or similar to retrieve the new form and display in current form?

```
$('#status-box').on('change', function() {
  // fire AJAX call to a route which renders
  // a .js.erb file 
  // you can use javascript here to append into DOM where you neeed it 
});
```